# Replace specific <p> with text from specific input onkeyup

Tags: input, onkeyup

I'm attempting to do something similar to https://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_live_text_input where when the user types into a field, their entry is visually displayed on another element.

The issue I'm running into is that his example is just calling all inputs, but I have two specific fields that I want to do this for, each with their own IDs and corresponding targets. As a novice, not sure how I would accomplish this. Also, his ticket includes reversing what's written and counting the characters, neither of which I need.

His JS:

```
 * one to set the content of an element.
 */

function reverse(s){return s.split('').reverse().join('')}

function set(el,text){
 while(el.firstChild)el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
 el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))}

/* setupUpdater will be called once, on page load.
 */

function setupUpdater(){
 var input=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
   , reversed=document.getElementById('reversed')
   , count=document.getElementById('charCount')
   , orig=document.getElementById('original')
   , oldText=input.value
   , timeout=null;

/* handleChange is called 50ms after the user stops 
   typing. */
 function handleChange(){
  var newText=input.value;
  if (newText==oldText) return; else oldText=newText;
  set(reversed, reverse(newText));
  set(count, 'You entered '+newText.length+' characters.');
  set(orig, newText);
 }

/* eventHandler is called on keyboard and mouse events.
   If there is a pending timeout, it cancels it.
   It sets a timeout to call handleChange in 50ms. */
 function eventHandler(){
  if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout=setTimeout(handleChange, 50);
 }

 input.onkeydown=input.onkeyup=input.onclick=eventHandler;
}

setupUpdater();
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find an easy answer to this:

```
<script>

    var inputBox = document.getElementById('form');

    inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
        document.getElementById('text-element').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
    }
    </script>
```